# hyper-v 1 network card same ip address

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I have a windows 10 laptop with hyper v enabled. I want to be able to have the virtual machine access the host as I am trying to restore an old laptop. I have set up Microsoft loop back network interface but that really didn't help me so I think that's just complicating things.

I have a bridged network pointing to my wifi card. When I look at the IP addresses they are the same.

What I want is two different IP addresses.

[image: Network Configuration]
[image: Guest IP Address]
[image: Host IP Address]

Comment: Hyper v config https://i.imgur.com/UZ21eFS.png

Comment: windows ipconfig 
https://i.imgur.com/WXyOOHs.png

Comment: heres the guest unix box https://i.imgur.com/SygaPjB.png

Heres the config in Hyper v https://i.imgur.com/DD2m1ks.png

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information that was provided in the question and also in comments

Here's what we know

- you have a Windows Host with IP as 192.168.0.51
- you have a unix host with same ip 192.168.0.51
- you have bridged networking

Regarding your question
What I want is two different IP addresses.

go inside your Unix host and update the IP address, change it to 192.168.0.52 or whatever you want.

It's hard to know with limited information, maybe your problem could be that you are using the same mac address for both windows and unix, so use a unique mac address and then your DHCP might assign unique ip address.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your wireless adapter isn't attached/bridged properly as a virtual switch, otherwise you won't see *`Ethernet 2`* from `ipconfig` but *`vEthernet (Bridged)`*:

[image]

Try to remove the switch and attach again to see if it changes.